# Rails respond_with is not outputting the status of the rest call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make a simple rest api with rails using the respond_with method, but it does not want to output any type of status message

for example, I want it to not only return the json for a get call but also a ok status. The same for when a post or delete works/fails.

Several tutorials suggest using additional :status parameters but they don't seem to affect the output at all.

```
  def index
    @conns = Connection.all
    respond_with(@conns, :status => :ok)
  end
```

This returns the same exact thing as if :status => :ok was not there.

Any ideas??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it would implicitly return `:status => :ok`, when the response is ok, which I guess it is :)

Try with another status code, like

```
:status => :not_found
```

There's a [full list of status codes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option) in the official ruby on rails guide.

Answer (score 8):

`:status => :ok` sets the status code of the HTTP header, i.e. it's the same as `:status => 200`. If you want to add something to the response body, you'll need to add it explicitly, e.g.

`respond_with({:conns => @conns, :status => :success}.to_json)`

**EDIT**

OK, so that doesn't work. If you don't need to respond to anything but JSON, you could just use good old `render`:

```
render :json => { :conns => @conns, :status => :success }
```

If you have to accommodate multiple response types with the bright and shiny new `respond_with` method, you could make a class that responds to `as_json`:

```
class JsonResponse
  def initialize(data,status)
    @data = data
    @status = status
  end
  def as_json(options={})
    {
    :data => @data,
    :status => @status
    }
  end
end
```

Then call it like so:

```
@conns = Connection.all
respond_with(JsonResponse.new(@conns,"success"))
```

Comment: turns out that doesnt work. because whatever is in responds_with gets a method called on it. so it keeps trying to call a method on a json string which throws errors

Comment: Eh? I don't follow. Do you mean `as_json` gets called on the ActiveRecord objects? That's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: it seems that by doing this whatever is inside the respond_with method get further processed inside of the method. So since your way converts it to a json string first, methods that are later applied to it fail because it's not an object, just a json string. it seems like responds_with needs an object as its parameter.